# Creating iOS Static Library with multiple libraries

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I'm currently trying to create my own iOS static library, which in turn relies on several static libraries. The overall architecture looks like this:

PersonalSDK

- libjpeg.a
- opencv2.framework

The PersonalSDK project compiles just fine, and I am able to add PersonalSDK into a sample app (PersonalApp). However, when trying to build PersonalApp, I am getting a whole rash of undefined symbol errors such as:

```
  "cv::copyMakeBorder(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int, int, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)", referenced from:
  Segmenter::segmentize(cv::Rect_<int>&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Size_<float>&, bool, bool) in personalSDK.a(Segmenter.o)

  "cv::findContours(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int, cv::Point_<int>)", referenced from:
  Segmenter::segmentize(cv::Rect_<int>&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Size_<float>&, bool, bool) in personalSDK.a(Segmenter.o)
```

Does anyone know how I should go about doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

After much trying, I have given up on using static libraries and have gone with using a framework instead!